# Как отслеживать, хочет пользователь зарегистрироваться через учетную запись Google или войти через учетную запись Google?

Tags: java, android, firebase-database

У меня есть метод записи данных в базе данных Firebase, но когда я пишу его в методе FirebaseAuthWithGoogle, при каждом нажатии на кнопку входа или регистрации через Google данные учетной записи перезаписываются, то есть, если человек регистрируется в приложении через Google, а затем выходит и пытается зайти, все его данные отменяются и записываются снова. Как сделать так, чтобы новые пользователи записывались в базу данных и уже зарегистрированные, просто вошли в свой аккаунт без перезаписи данных? На всякий случай поясню еще раз на примере, новый пользователь нажимает кнопку "Войти через Google" его аккаунт зарегистрирован в Firebase базу, проверка подлинности и все необходимые мне данные, которые вы можете увидеть в WriteNewUser заносятся в базу данных и после того, как пользователь зашел он выбрал своего героя, и это также записывается в базу данных, но как только он выйдет и войдет в свою учетную запись, как будет сработает WriteNewUser и все, что он получил, прежде чем он будет сброшен.
Если я выйду и войду в свою учетную запись, все эти данные будут перезаписаны
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wZrd.png

OnCreate:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    findViewById(R.id.create).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.signinwithEmail).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.signInGoogle).setOnClickListener(this);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();




    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();


    mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);


    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
```

OnActivityResult:

```
   public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);

        try {

            GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
            assert account != null;
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);

        } catch (ApiException e) {

            Log.w(TAG, "Ошибка входа", e);

            updateUI(null);

        }
    }
}
```

FirebaseAuthWithGoogle: Here and there is an overwrite or record

```
 private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Аутентификация" + acct.getId());

     String account = acct.getEmail();



    showProgressDialog();


    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, task -> {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                    Log.d(TAG, "Успешно");
                    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                    updateUI(user);
                    writeNewUser(account,getUid());  //Here I call the write or overwrite method
```

The whole code of registration and login a Google user:

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
private static final String TAG = "Registration";
private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;


private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;


private GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    findViewById(R.id.create).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.signinwithEmail).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.signInGoogle).setOnClickListener(this);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();




    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();


    mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);


    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


}


@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    FirebaseUser
            user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    updateUI(user);
}
private void updateUI(FirebaseUser user) {
    if (user != null) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MenuActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);

        try {

            GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
            assert account != null;
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);

        } catch (ApiException e) {

            Log.w(TAG, "Ошибка входа", e);

            updateUI(null);

        }
    }
}

private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Аутентификация" + acct.getId());

     String account = acct.getEmail();



    showProgressDialog();


    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, task -> {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                    Log.d(TAG, "Успешно");
                    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                    updateUI(user);
                    writeNewUser(account,getUid()); //Here I call the write or overwrite method


                } else {

                    Log.w(TAG, "Ошибка", task.getException());
                    updateUI(null);
                }


                hideProgressDialog();

            });
}




private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);

}

private void writeNewUser(String userId, String account) {

    GoogleUser user = new GoogleUser(account, 0);

    mDatabase.child("users").child(userId).setValue(user);
    mDatabase.child("users").child(userId).child("coupons").child("petiarochka").child("petiarochka100").setValue(0);
    mDatabase.child("users").child(userId).child("coupons").child("petiarochka").child("petiarochka300").setValue(0);
    mDatabase.child("users").child(userId).child("coupons").child("petiarochka").child("petiarochka500").setValue(0);
    mDatabase.child("users").child(userId).child("coupons").child("lenta").child("lenta100").setValue(0);
    mDatabase.child("users").child(userId).child("coupons").child("lenta").child("lenta300").setValue(0);
    mDatabase.child("users").child(userId).child("coupons").child("lenta").child("lenta500").setValue(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё просто. У объекта `FirebaseUser` есть `ID`. Когда юзер заходит через к-л соц.сеть делайте запрос в БД на предмет наличия там записи для этого юзера. Если она есть - значит юзер не в первый раз зашёл; иначе - в первый раз. В этом случае пишите его в вашу БД. Так он в следующий раз будет признан ранее авторизовывашимся.

Возможно будет вам вот эта ссылка полезна: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users

Comment: Окей. я понял ваш ответ, но не понимаю как делать запрос на наличие,  то есть я понимаю, что надо if(getUid==null(в БД) но не понимаю какой метод нужен для поиска в БД

Comment: Надеюсь понятно объяснил

Comment: @georgiy110802, я у себя просто создавал запись в БД при регистрации. ID был взят из юзера. Создавал, если нет такой записи. Как её получить... Код не помню, но это простейшая операция с БД - надо в документацию смотреть.

Comment: Окей,спасибо большое